# Problem from Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and its Applications, Section 1.8

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

> Let S = X1  * Y1 + X2 * Y2 + · · · + Xn * Yn,  where X1, X2 , . . . ,
>   Xn and Y1, Y2, . . . , Yn are orderings of two different sequences of
>   positive real numbers, each containing n elements.
>
> a) Show that Stakes its maximum value overall orderings of the two
>   sequences when both sequences are sorted (so that the elements in each
>   sequence are in nondecreasing order).

*I am new to mathematical proof and I really suffer from it, can anyone please help me with this problem?*